# Can Spring Parse and Inject Properties Files?

Tags: java, spring, configuration-files

I already know how to:

Load properties files into my Spring configuration using:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="aaa/bbb/ccc/stuff.properties"/>
```

Build properties objects on the fly using:

```
<props><prop key="abc">some value</prop></props>
```

But what I cant do, and would be really useful, is to have Spring load a properties file and then build the matching properties object. I could then inject this into a bean in the normal way.

I've searched for this elsewhere without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at [**util:properties**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties)

```
<util:properties id="myProperties" location="classpath:com/foo/my.properties"/>
```

Then, to inject the Properties into your Spring-managed Bean, it's as simple as this:

```
@Resource(name = "myProperties")
private Properties myProperties;
```